# EditText/Spinner/Button special style in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-button

**Dears,**

I want to achieve the following design:

[image: Layout Desired]

**Problems:**

1. Unable to set padding for the hint text inside the EditText.

**Code:**

```
<EditText
    style="@style/txtBoxStyle"
    android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_username"
    android:hint="@string/text_username">
</EditText>
```

**Style:**

```
<style name="txtBoxStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:ems">10</item>                              
</style>
```

2. Can't add icon for the spinner on the left side.

**Code:**

```
<Spinner
    style="@style/ddlStyle"
    android:id="@+id/lstCountry"/>
```

**Style:**

```
<style name="ddlStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/ic_country</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_country</item>
</style>
```

3. Can't align the image and text inside the button to center.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

To give padding between your image and hint text you should have to use android property

**android:drawablePadding="10dp"**